# Can I get a Maverick hat for answering Meta questions?

Tags: support, meta, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

If I answer a -3 question, which later becomes a +3 question, on Meta StackOverflow, would that achieve me the [Maverick](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/maverick) hat?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No. You cannot earn hats for actions on Meta sites (unless the hat itself explicitly mentions it, like ['I Am Your Father'](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/i-am-your-father)). So you cannot earn Maverick by posting an answer on Meta Stack Overflow.

From the last paragraph of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/295232):

> Most hats are awarded for things you do on the **main site**, but there are a few that are awarded for performing an action on the site's meta. Their requirement generally includes the words "on meta".
>
> ...
>
> Meta Stack Exchange is a bit special in this regard, because it's both a main site and a meta site. For the purposes of Winter Bash, Meta Stack Exchange counts as its own child meta.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: This is not correct. I also have "Abominable" and "Egoist" on meta.se. Neither of those hat descriptions mention "on meta"

Comment: @DavidPostill , *meta.se* is a standalone community website just like *security.se* and *softwareengineering.se* ... You have separate reputation there. As opposed to *meta.stackoverflow* and *meta.security.stackexchange.com* where your reputation is shared with the main community website. That's why you can earn hats on *meta.se* that you can not earn here.

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah, I expanded the quote a little bit to make this more clear.