# Is it possible to to earn the "Silencium"-hat on meta?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2018

Is it possible to to earn the "Silencium"-hat on meta by playing the meta-game?

[image: Winter bash silencium hat capture with freehand circle]

Comment: Technically even a closed question should earn it eventually.

Comment: Let's all return to this question in 7 days to see.

Comment: Sorry, your question is too interesting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is highly probably **no**. In the past, hats which trigger on Meta sites have always been explicit about this, such as [Member of The Hand](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/member-of-the-hand) (*+3 post as new contributor, meta or main*) and [Freehand Circle](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/freehand-circle) (*earn the Nice Answer badge on meta*). Other hats trigger only on main site events, see e.g. [Can I get a Maverick hat for answering Meta questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340297/4751173)

You *can* earn this badge on Meta Stack Exchange because that's both a main and a meta site for the purpose of Winter Bash.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Although it is disappointing in two different ways. :)

Comment: Spoilsport.. ;)

Comment: Partypooper.. ;)

Comment: Nah, @Glorfindel is just so proud he has a hat on meta, he doesn't want anyone else to get one. /s